# BTSync: Intall Bittorent Sync silently with no prompts on Ubuntu Server 14

Tags: apt, sync, bittorrent, automation

Trying to install `btsync` in fully automatic mode - silent, without any prompts.

I try to use `assume yes` feature of `apt` and also `DEBIAN_FRONTEND` env variable, but have no luck:

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:tuxpoldo/btsync
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get --assume-yes -y install btsync
```

Also I have found [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7740571/734493) about mysql password but similar problem.
They solve it via `debconf-set-selections` tool.

Where to get those selections for `debconf-set-selections` tool so I can predefine them or any other way to automate install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done without `apt` by this:

```
echo "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main universe" > /etc/apt/sources.list
apt-get update

# Download and extract the executable to /usr/bin
curl -o /usr/bin/btsync.tar.gz http://download-new.utorrent.com/endpoint/btsync/os/linux-x64/track/stable
cd /usr/bin && tar -xzvf btsync.tar.gz && rm btsync.tar.gz

btsync
```

[via Dockerfile](https://github.com/FelikZ/docker-btsync/blob/master/Dockerfile)